# Web GL not supported

Tags: 14.04, graphics, intel-graphics, webgl

Whenever I try to play a WebGL game in my HP 15 r247tu it says that WebGL is not supported.
I tried everything found on forums including chrome://flags Overriding blacklist,installing mesa-utils and everything but still no luck.

And also when it's booting up I get an error message saying:

```
error: driver i915 is already registered.
error: hda-intel error request power-well from i915
```

And there's an error with sound which makes it glitch at some points..but it's not a big problem for now.

And when I'm launching an AVD it says that it couldn't start it with Direct3D and used software rendering.

I'm posting all these things as I think those may be related.

---

And here's my specs:

```
HP 15 r247tu with Intel® Core™ i3-5010U CPU @ 2.10GHz × 4
Intel HD5500 Broadwell Graphics
4GB of RAM
```

and I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it fixed myself.
did `apt-get dist-upgrade` and the graphics errors were fixed. (including WebGL)

but the sound glitches are still present.

Answering my own question so it might be helpful to someone else having the same problem and no community support. :)

Thank you.